# Select latest message from conversation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, conversation_tbl and conversation_reply_tbl

```
conversation_reply_tbl
-------------------------
|  conversation_reply_id|   //auto increment id      
|  reply_message        |   //message text
|  user_id              |   //the user who sent the message
|  datetime_sent        |   //date and time of message sent
|  status               |   //values '0' or '1' (read or not)
|  conversation_id      |   //relation to the conversation
-------------------------

conversation_tbl
-------------------------
|  conversation_id      |    //auto increment id     
|  from_user            |    //the user who sent the message
|  to_user              |    //the recipient
|  datetime_created     |    //date of the message created
|  gallery_id           |//the gallery where the message started from
-------------------------
```

Now I use the `conversation_reply_tbl` to store all the messages that go on in a conversation and `conversation_tbl` to store the conversation main data.

Now, I want  to select all conversations that the user is involved in but I want to show the most recent message of every conversation, just like how it's done in famous websites and apps such as 'WhatsApp' or 'Facebook'.

Could this be done in one query or do I have to use a function with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can get that information with one query:

```
select     t.*,
           last.*
from       conversation_tbl t
inner join (select   conversation_id, max(conversation_reply_id) conversation_reply_id
            from     conversation_reply_tbl
            group by conversation_id) all_lasts
        on all_lasts.conversation_id = t.conversation_id
inner join conversation_reply_tbl last
        on last.conversation_reply_id = all_lasts.conversation_reply_id
left join  (select   conversation_id 
            from     conversation_reply_tbl
            where    user_id = :the_user_id
            group by conversation_id) user_conv
        on user_conv.conversation_id = t.conversation_id
where      (     user_conv.conversation_id is not null
           or    t.to_user = :the_user_id )
```

Note the `left join`, as it might be that the targeted user has not yet replied with a message, but was the *to_user* of the starting message. The `where` clause makes an `or` of both situations: if the message thread has a message of the user, or if the user is the target of the initiating message, the query should return that conversation.

Comment: Hey there @trincot, I am sorry to bother you, but there is a slight issue with the query that you have given me, when I send a message and a new conversation is started, the message won't be shown on the recipient side because there is no data of him on the `conversation_reply_tbl`

Comment: I updated the query: in an additional paragraph I explain the changes.

Comment: Thank you so much once again @trincot, now it works :)!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, something like this would provide you with the record if provided the appropriate conversation_id.

Get the conversations which the users is a part of

```
SELECT conversation_id FROM conversation_tbl WHERE from_user = ?
```

With that id, get the last message that was sent.

```
SELECT datetime_sent, reply_message FROM conversation_reply_tbl
WHERE datetime_sent IN (SELECT MAX(datetime_sent)
FROM conversation_reply_tbl WHERE conversation_id = ? )
```

Comment: Thank you @KadeM. but I have gone with "trincot's" method above.. It is more efficient and crammed in one query.

Comment: Understandable :). It's nice getting multiple solutions, as we never truly know how you'll use it. One of us is bound to get it right! Glad you got what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you save all the conversation messages under reply_message column of conversation_reply_tbl table.

In that case, you can try this

```
SELECT T2.conversation_id, T2.reply_message
FROM conversation_tbl T1  INNER JOIN  conversation_reply_tbl T2 ON 
T1.conversation_id = T2.conversation_id
WHERE (T1.from_user = $userID OR T1.to_user = $userID)
GROUP BY T1.conversation_id
ORDER BY T2.datime_sent DESC;
```